# Appending new lines to a text file, and then retrieving them later Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

TLDR; writing to file results in goofy file reading later.

I am attempting to create a grid of numbers in a file and then later call them back.

This is my code:

```
data = []
if os.path.isfile("./" + fname):
    with open(fname, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            data.append(line.split(","))
else:
    f = open(fname,"w+")
    for i in range(3):
        f.write("0,0,0")
        data.append(["0","0","0"])
    f.close()
print(data)
```

Simply put, the above code checks to see if a file named the same as `fname` exists. If not, it creates a new file, otherwise, it stores the "grid" of values as `data`.

As expected, when I first run it, it prints `[["0","0","0"],["0","0","0"],["0","0","0"]]`, and creates a new file `XXXXXXXX.txt`. What goes wrong is that when you run it again, it prints `[['0', '0', '00', '0', '00', '0', '0']]`, which is wrong. Upon examining the file, the information stored is `0,0,00,0,00,0,0`, NOT:

```
0,0,0
0,0,0
0,0,0
```

If I use `f.write("0,0,0\n")`, the file looks fine, but the program prints `[['0', '0', '0\n'], ['0', '0', '0\n'], ['0', '0', '0']]`, which is still wrong.

I am very confused, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
for line in f:
```

does not remove `'\n'` at end of lines.
=> When reading and splitting, your last `0` will have the `'\n'` still in it.

This

```
 f.write("0,0,0")
```

does not autoappend a `'\n'`.
=> If you continue to write into the file it will be placed directly after the `0`, leading to `0,0,00,0,00,0,0`.

**Fix:**
(includes some code to make it an mvce and fix for `f = opne(...)` wich is bad:

```
import os
fname = "test.txt"

data = []
if os.path.isfile("./" + fname):
    with open(fname, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            data.append(line.rstrip('\n').split(",")) # strip '\n'
else:
    with open(fname,"w+") as f:  # do not use f = open(fname,"w+") - it will not auto-
                                 # magically close your filehandle if errors get thrown
        for i in range(3):
            f.write("0,0,0\n")   # add '\n'

            data.append(["0","0","0"])

print(data)
```

Comment: Can you tell me why f.write(str) doesn't automatically add the str argument to a new line as it supposedly does in [online examples](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python)?

Comment: @TheEye I would blame it on a bad tutorial after checking if there are differences when writing files in 3.6 an 2.7 - they have differences in many regards. I am mainly using 3.6 and there you need to apply the \n yourself. According to pyfiddle.io, 2.7 and 2.6 behave the same - no newline.

Answer (score 1):

To write the rows to file, use:

```
f.write("0,0,0\n")
```

While reading from the file, remove the new line char with:

```
data.append(line.rstrip('\n').split(","))
```

Answer (score -1):

I sense your problem is more about the `data` incorrectly printing (or not printing how you want it to). Thhe reason the `\n` in your `data` list isn't displayed how you want it is because you're not directly printing that index (kind of how `__str__` and `__repr__` differ, but you can see that later). So you have to access each index individually rather than the entire list, which can be done with a `for` loop.

```
for layer1 in data:
    print(layer1)
```

If you try this, you can see, that this will not work either. This is because the `data` list is composed of even more lists, rather than strings. If you were to replace each list with a string with `\n`, it would work. But you want to have lists in a list. Kind of reminds you of something nested, right? Well you can use a **nested** `for` loop (get it... because the list reminds you of something nested, and there's nested for loops...yeah ok). So what you do is just create another for loop.

```
for layer1 in data:
    for layer2 in layer1: # not for layer2 ib data
        print(layer2)
```

This will print the 0's and create new lines where needed. However, it will do this without any commas, giving you an output like this:

```
000
000
000
```

You can fix this by including commas in the actual string that is being appended to `data`.

I hope this helps!

Comment: do not "sense" - read the question. it is about "examining the file, the information stored is 0,0,00,0,00,0,0, NOT:0,0,0\n0,0,0\n0,0,0\n" (as well as printing incorrectly) - the latter being the result of the former.